# Is it OK to store information regarding an error in an Exception object?

Tags: c++, exception

I've been reading about exceptions in C++, the pros and cons, and I've yet to encounter anyone mention the two things I really like about them: They allow me to extend the definition of an error (to something that is more than just an error message as a string), and, they allow me to define a contract between the exception handler and the thrower:

> "If I'm going to handle this particular type of error, I'm going to
>   need this, this and that from you."

I've not seen this mentioned in any of the articles, forums and blog posts, as a pro *or* a con. And that has made me suspect that my mindset on exceptions and how they should be used may be wrong.

To clarify, here's an example of my usage of exceptions:

A program communicates with a USB device (it sends commands to the device and expects a certain response from it). This USB device can sometimes behave in an unexpected way when responding to a command. In this case, the program will throw an `UnexpectedResponseFromDevice` exception. The handler for this exception needs more than just an error message in order to do its job. For example, it may need to know of the command that we were sending to the device when the error occurred, and/or the state the device was in. I use the definition of my `UnexpectedResponseFromDevice` class to explicitly set out what is required to handle the exception. See below for a rough idea.

```
class UnexpectedResponseFromDevice : public std::exception
{
private:
    Command command;
    DeviceState deviceState;
    std::string msg;

public:
    UnexpectedResponseFromDevice(std::string msg, Command command, DeviceState deviceState, ...)
    Command getCommand();
    DeviceState getDeviceState();
};
```

This is what I meant by "define a contract between the exception handler and the thrower". In order to throw the exception, these things (in this case a Command, a DeviceState and a message) need to be provided.

Is this an acceptable use case for exceptions? Is it OK for me to store this other information, that is required for the handling of the exception, in the exception object? Is it acceptable but a bad idea? If so, please explain why.

Comment: I chuckled a bit seeing *unexpected* misspelled (in an exception).

Comment: doh! Will fix....

Comment: Yes, but be cautious. You do not want to throw an exception while throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this an acceptable use case for exceptions? Is it OK for me to store this other information, that is required for the handling of the exception, in the exception object?

Yes, that's how the exceptions in the standard library do too. One example is [`std::system_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error) that derives from `std::runtime_error` but adds a [`std::error_code`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code) member to carry extra information. One that adds a lot more is [`std::filesystem::filesystem_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/filesystem_error) that adds two `std::filesystem::path` objects.

> Is it acceptable but a bad idea? If so, please explain why.

It's only a bad idea if you risk throwing another exception (like a `std::bad_alloc`) while throwing your exception - or if you use exceptions as something else than *exceptions*, like choosing between common branches in your program flow. Throwing should preferably be a rare event.

If your have all the info you need in a `std::string`, or even in something like a `std::stack<std::string>>`, member variable in the object that is a about to `throw` you can probably `std::move` that member object into the exception object to minimize the risk - if you don't need that data anymore in the object that is throwing that is.

I don't know how big your `std::string`, `Command` and `DeviceState` objects are, but you may not want to construct the exception object by taking the parameters by value. Try to make construction `noexcept`. The getters should also probably return by `const&`. That's not *as* critical - but making them so minimizes the risk of an exception in your exception handler.

Comment: Thanks again Ted for another great answer. I don't think I could pass by reference to the constructor of the exception, as the stack would be unwound when the exception is thrown (I think), and both objects are stored on the stack.

Comment: @JohnO'brien Oh, hi and welcome again :-) The exception object will live until the end of the `catch(...) { ...} /* <- here it is destroyed */`. Standard exceptions usually take a `const&` and copy the data. The copying can be done "late", after initialization, in a `try/catch` to be able to make it reasonably safe. You could also make a constructor that takes expensive payload by `&&` and moves it into the exception and it'll also be destroyed at the end of the `catch`.

Comment: That is fascinating! I will look further into that this weekend. Thanks again, Ted!

Comment: @JohnO'brien You're welcome! You may also want to take a look at the wonderful world of [nested exceptions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/nested_exception). I must admit I haven't used those much but they do look nice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a parameter is handed over. By means of it information is made available.
catch(const exception& e) { e....; }